# How to replace the default handler with user defined handler in Linux kernel that handles the exceptions generating core dump?

Tags: linux, signals, signal-handling

I am working on "Creation of Postmortem data logger on Linux platform". I posted a question regarding this project previously also. There, i got the call flow mechanism of core dump file creation in RHEL version: 2.6.18.128-el5.

It follows as:

```
File                                       Function called
1.source/ arch/i386/kernel/signal.c -----> do_signal( )
2.source/kernel/signal.c       ----------> get_signal_to_deliver( )
3.source/fs/exec.c          -------------> do_coredump( )
4.source/fs/binfmt_elf.c    -------------> elf_core_dump( )
```

Now,as per project requirements, i need to modify the default signal handler definitions with my own user defined signal handler that handles various exceptions (`SIGSEGV`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGABRT` etc) causing coredump. Further, i need to build the kernel for keeping the changes in kernel with my handler replacing default handler.

Can anybody please share the proceedings to do those operations ?

Advance thanks to all repliers:)

Thanks
vlc

Comment: Do you want to change way how kernel works or you what to set signal handlers in your user-mode code?

Comment: yeah...i want to know how the kernel exactly works in generating coredump. Based on that, i want to modify the default handlers with my own handler and build kernel.Thus, i want to operate on that new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

SIGFPE, SIGABRT, SIGSEGV and some others already generate a core dump by default, see [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html). However, many distros set the core file size resource limit to 0, disabling core dump generation. You can reenable it by:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Instead of `unlimited`, you can pass the maximum number of filesystem blocks core dumps should  take.